# GitHub - "This Binary file has been changed"

Tags: github

Every time I simply view the code of my repository, when I return to the GitHub Desktop app, it says I have to make a new commit as "this binary file has been changed" relating to the Xcode user Interface. This  occurs even though I've made zero edits to the code. I don't even know what a binary file is.

Comment: You probably want to [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) that file.

Comment: what does "gitignore that file" mean @Smitop?

Comment: @Gabriella putting the file path in the `.gitignore` file